RefNames consisting of 40 hex characters are not allowed
I am trying to push my gitlab clone repo to Azure devops using gitbash
$ git push -u --mirror
Enumerating objects: 25827, done.
Counting objects: 100% (25827/25827), done.
Delta compression using up to 8 threads
Compressing objects: 100% (6709/6709), done.
Writing objects: 100% (25827/25827), 5.81 MiB | 106.20 MiB/s, done.
Total 25827 (delta 19021), reused 25827 (delta 19021), pack-reused 0
remote: Analyzing objects… (25827/25827) (2636 ms)
remote: Validating commits… (4694/4694) done (1151 ms)
remote: Storing packfile… done (162 ms)
remote: Storing index… done (119 ms)
TXXX(RefNames consisting of 40 hex characters are not allowed.)

I have posted on Azure dev community if there is any workaround to over come this problem and the problem will occur even if we Push from local or add in UI. Is there a solution for this problem without renaming the branches/files?

This is limit for the branch name on DevOps git repo. Currently we have to rename the branch name, then can push to DevOps repo, there's no workaround yet. Please check the details below, let me know if you have any queries, thanks.

This is limit for the branch name on DevOps git repo.


Is there a solution for this problem without renaming the branches/files?

Currently we have to rename the branch name, then can push to DevOps repo, there's no workaround yet.
We can rename local branch via command git branch -m <oldbranch> <newbranch>.
I'm totally understand your concern, if you would like the name limit change, it's recommended to raise a suggestion ticket on community link, thanks.
